# Gradle 6 with Intellij - refresh fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a gradle 6.0 project with Spring 2.1.7.

When I try to `refresh all gradle projects` from intellij [image]

I got an error:

> Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I use intellij v 2018.3.4 and I've configured it to use the gradle wrapper:

[image]

The gradle-wrapper.properties looks like this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

If I run the gradle wrapper from command line there are not problems. Also If I trigger a gradle task (build, clean ...) from Intellij I have no errors.

I have another wired issue that could be related to this one. In my build.gradle I use spring boot 2.1.7 and If I run my jar from the command line I can see from the Spring Boot banner the configured version 2.1.7.
Instead If I run the application form Intellij I see that It is using Spring Boot 2.0.8, also if I expand the External libraries tree I see:
[image]

the build.gradle looks like:

```
buildscript {
 ext {
   springBootVersion = "2.1.7.RELEASE"
   springBootDepManagementVersion = "1.0.8.RELEASE"
 }
}
plugins {
 id 'idea'
 id 'java'
 id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "${springBootDepManagementVersion}"
 id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
}
dependencies {
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
   ....
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It could very well be that your version of IntelliJ does not support Gradle 6.0. Your version is almost a year old. Can't you upgrade?

Comment: @BjørnVester Unfortunatelly I cannot upgrade intellij. I thought that setting intellij to use the wrapper it would have been gradle-version indipendent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem downgrading the gradle wrapper to 5.6.4.
Apparently my Intellij version does not support gradle 6.0.0

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading also do the job for me:

```
gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.6.4
```